# bytes meaning in mongodb, _id collection in each document

Tags: mongodb

what is the meaning of each bytes existing in the _id property in mongodb collections. in mongodb's site there were three meaningful values:

a 4-byte timestamp value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch (which will not run out of seconds until the year 2106)
a 5-byte random value, and
a 3-byte incrementing counter, starting with a random value.

but also as mosh hamedany and chatGPT said:
It is a 12-byte BSON type, which consists of a 4-byte timestamp, a 3-byte machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter.

witch of them is true?

Comment: ChatGPT may not be a reliable source of truth in the domain of programming/software engineering. That's why it is [banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) on Stackoverflow. Generally for any technology, the most reputable reference about its behaviour would be the official document.

Comment: @ray ChatGPT is not a source of thruch in any domain. ChatGPT users are responsible of verifiy the accuracy of it responses.

Answer (score 1):

The [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/) says:

> ObjectId()
>
> **Returns a new ObjectId. The 12-byte ObjectId consists of:**
>
> - A 4-byte timestamp, representing the ObjectId's creation, measured in seconds since the Unix epoch.
> - A 5-byte random value generated once per process. This random value is unique to the machine and process.
> - A 3-byte incrementing counter, initialized to a random value.

When you go back to documentation of [MongoDB version 3.2](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.2/reference/bson-types/#objectid), it is a little more detailed:

> - a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
> - a 3-byte machine identifier,
> - a 2-byte process id, and
> - a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

And if you like to know the details, have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/bson/oid.h)